# OnClientClick event not firing - When Disabled on the beginning

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

This is special case i think: 
I have Asp.net Button, which working and fire OnClientClick & OnClick evens fine.
But - when the initial state of the button is:

```
Enabled="False"
```

Then, when i make it enabled again (using jquery):

```
$('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
```

and i click on it - so ONLY OnClick firing but OnClientClick is not !

Some ideas please ?..

Comment: To be sure that OnClientClick isn't working, i deleted OnClick absoloutley, and it didn't help. Seems that OnClientClick isn't recognized at all ..!

Comment: Please check whether OnClientClick  also has same 'btn' as its id?If so, please change the id's to class as id's should be unique.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal, Thanks! Yes, it's the same ID. If it wasn't - the OnClick event couldn't be fired.. but it is. and OnClientClick isn't. I tried with the IE debugger, but cannot find there any thing..

Comment: Could you please provide the full jquery and .net codes  for both buttons.